# How to run a command in a new gnome-terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

I want to run some commands on some servers.

So, I created a bash file:

```
#!/bin/sh
for n in `cat ~/nodes`; do
        gnome-terminal -x ssh root@$n
        ANYCOMMAND
done
```

The connections are established in new terminals.

How could I apply ANYCOMMAND on each server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proposal:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r n; do
  </dev/null ssh root@$n "ANYCOMMAND"
done < ~/nodes
```

Comment: You are right. However, It runs the command and exit. Would you please tell me how to keep my ssh connection

Comment: You can try something like this: `</dev/null ssh -X root@$n "ANYCOMMAND; gnome-terminal"`

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools available for running commands on many hosts at the same time synchronously. Some of them open up terminal windows in X (e.g. ClusterSSH), most are for running commands on CLI:

http://web.taranis.org/shmux/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mussh/

http://pydsh.sourceforge.net/

https://github.com/Ticketmaster/onall

http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/

https://code.google.com/p/omnissh/wiki/OmniSSH

https://code.google.com/p/pdsh/

http://www.theether.org/pssh/

http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en

https://github.com/ndenev/mpssh

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pussh/

For nearly all tools you have the possibility to send commands and additionally have interactive shells. Otherwise sending commands to servers runs the commands instead of having interactive login shells.